# permission denied when logging in to mysql, but able to login from cmd digitalocean

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, digital-ocean

I have created a droplet with digitalocean and installed `mariadb` using the `apt install mariadb-server` command. Now I want to connect to my server using `php` and I use this:

```
mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
```

The problem is I always have `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` error. I don't understand why this happens. I can login using `mysql -uroot` when I am logged into my server. Also when I create a new user using

```
CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost';
```

I can connect using `php mysqli_connect`. What am I doing wrong? Why can't I connect with `root`?

Comment: Let's see the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

To connect this with server you need to create a database user first, and after creating user associate it with your database then the error will go away. hope this work for you. :) 
Goto MySQL Database > Create new user > Add the user with the database you want to use Like this: [Check this for have a look how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhIJw.png) > Then simply use this `mysqli_connect("host", "your_created_user", "your_user_password", "DB_name");`

Comment: Yes but why can I not connect using `root`? It should work for every database right?

Comment: No it required to have a username and password for security purpose. So please give a try and if this help then vote it

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","my_db");

// Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

To create User

```
CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'test'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTIO
```

Comment: Yes but why can I not connect using `root`? It should work for every database right?

Comment: You gave password as root and trying to connect with ' ' how it work ?

Comment: Please check the syntax here https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp